# How to include /sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css and /default.css into symfony project?

Tags: css, plugins, symfony-1.4

I have downloaded plugin sfPropelORMPlugin, but I don't know how to load it into symfony project.

I have checked source of page but it only has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/main.css" />
```

Where should I include it?

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html .  This will help you understand CSS Stylesheets.

Comment: I know how works stylesheet but I don't know how to add it into Symfony project. I have my styles in directory: /sfProject1/web/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css and /default.css

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what do you want.

Once you have installed sfPropelORMPlugin and [configured it](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/README.md), you should run this command to move (or create a symlink to) css into the web folder:

```
php symfony plugins:publish-assets
```

Then, you will have css inside the /web folder, like you said `/web/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/...`.

sfPropelORMPlugin stylesheets will be automatically included in your admin generator module, and crud module. But if you need them in an other place (a custom module for example), just include them like a normal css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/default.css" />
```

Comment: I have inside /web my .css files. I have also included those files like you wrote above (in frontend/templates/layout.php), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run the symfony command about `plugins:publish-assets`? Do you have other plugin with CSS that doesn't work? Are other css from Symfony works? Which web server do you run? What is the web server configuration, default one? Provide all answer in your question for a better readability. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I have run this command. No, I don't have other plugin (actually sfPropelORMPlugin works on backend application, just not on frontend). I have apache server with default configuration.